# How would I take the java code I wrote and make the calculation be able to do degrees?

Tags: java

I would like to take my cubic function calculator and make a possiblity to be able to use degrees. How would I alter the code to do so?

```
    c.println("Welcome to this program which will help you solve a cubic function");    //top text
c.println ("");
c.println("Please enter coefficients in the following form");                       //explaining the format
c.println("f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d");


c.print(" Enter your X value: ");               //asking for the x value
double x = c.readDouble();

c.print("Enter your first coefficient (a): ");  //asking for the x value
double a = c.readDouble();

c.print("Enter your second coefficient (b): "); //asking for the x value
double b = c.readDouble();


c.print("Enter your third coefficient (c): ");  //asking for the x value
double c1 = c.readDouble();

c.print("Enter your last coefficient (d): ");   //asking for the x value
double d = c.readDouble();

c.println(CubicFunction(x,a,b,c1,d),0,2);       //prints out the final result, rounded to 2 decimals
c.println ("");

int choice = 1; // initializes choice to 1 so it can enter the main loop

while (done == false)   //main loop
```

Comment: f(x)  = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d
 so x cubes and squares
 you want to make that 3 and 2 a single variable that you can manipulate

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `CubicFunction` method does the calculation and returns the result. You would need to modify this code to perform the different calculation or return the different result. The code you supplied above doesn't actually do any calculations at all.

Its probably also a good idea to change the name of the `CubicFunction` method to start with a lowercase letter (ie `cubicFunction`), or maybe name it something slightly more meaningful (ie `calculateCubicFunction`) - your code was confusing me, I thought `CubicFunction` was a Class.

Comment: Awesome ! thanks, great help, I will do that, a few of lines are in the making!

Comment: Apologies. I will correct this when writing the code once I find the needed stuff to add degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Use the java.lang.Math class to access trig functions

Comment: I will give it a try, how exactly do I access these functions, do I just type it in my code where it is needed?

Comment: at the top text
 f(x)  = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d
 so x cubes and squares
 you want to make that 3 and 2 a single variable that you can manipulate

Comment: so what would the new equation look like?   Introduce new variables if you have to.

Comment: you want to give the user the option so he switches the degrees (3 and 2)
 so make those a single variable
 make sure you define it in the method as well
 then ask the user and all that
 or make a new option (enter 4 to change degrees) where you'll do all this

Comment: (Math.pow(x,3)*a) + (Math.pow(x,2)*b) + (x*c1) + d

Comment: Cool. So plug this formula in as a java expression instead of calling CubicFunction.

Comment: I dont write as much code as most, I am just learning java, how would I go about writing the formula as a java expression? ( Im not asking you to do it, but some tips, pointers, or even a link would be great. )